# Count features for different ids in columns in R in faster way

Tags: r, bigdata

I am trying to process a 20 GB data file in R. I have 16 gigs RAM and i7 processor. I am reading the data using :

```
y<-read.table(file="sample.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", skip =0, nrows =50000000)
```

The dataset 'y' is as follows :

```
id    feature

21    234
21    290
21    234
21    7802
21    3467
21    234
22    235
22    235
22    1234
22    236
22    134
23    9133
23    223
23    245
23    223  
23    122
23    223
```

So above is sample dataset, which shows different features for a particular id. I want to count how many times a particular  feature listed in another dataset x has occurred for an id in y.

The dataset x is as follows:

```
id    feature

   21      234
   22      235
   23      223
```

And the final output that I want is as follows:

```
 id    feature_count

   21      3
   22      2
   23      3
```

As we see 234 occurred thrice for 21, 235 occurred twice for 22 and 223 occurred twice for 23.

For this I have tried getting positions where the new id starts: (eg 1st, 7th and 12th position for above sample) and then count a feature using a for loop as follows:

#### Getting positions of different ids

```
positions=0
positions[1]=1
j=2
for(i in 1:50000000){
    if(y$id[i]!=y$id[i+1]){
    positions[j]=i+1
    j=j+1
  }
}
```

Since the data is huge the looping is taking a lots of time.(for 50 Million rows it takes 321 secs on above mentioned config PC and I have 300 Million rows).

#### Counting the features that match with the given feature in 'x'.( x is the data frame specified above from which the features are to be matched with that of y .On being matched feature_count is incremented)

```
for(i in 1 :length(positions)){
  for(j in positions[i]:positions[i+1]){
    if(y$feature[j]==x$feature[i]){         
       feature_count[i]=feature_count[i]+1
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any R functions which can collectively do this job for me in a faster time.
Also incrementing for loop using "positions[i]:positions[i+1]" throws an error saying NA arguments in for loop. Please suggest a right way to do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit that I don't really understand the question the way it is written, but it sounds like "data.table" would be the way to go, and you should look into the `.N` function. As already mentioned `fread` is going to be much better than `read.csv`, so I'll assume that you've read the data into a `data.table` named "DT".

Here's a small one:

```
DT <- data.table(id = c(rep(21, 6), rep(22, 5), 23, 23),
                 feature = c(234, 290, 234, 7802, 3467, 234, 235,
                             235, 1234, 236, 134, 9133, 223))
DT
#     id feature
#  1: 21     234
#  2: 21     290
#  3: 21     234
#  4: 21    7802
#  5: 21    3467
#  6: 21     234
#  7: 22     235
#  8: 22     235
#  9: 22    1234
# 10: 22     236
# 11: 22     134
# 12: 23    9133
# 13: 23     223
```

If you just wanted to count the number of each unique feature, you could do:

```
DT[, .N, by = "id,feature"]
#     id feature N
#  1: 21     234 3
#  2: 21     290 1
#  3: 21    7802 1
#  4: 21    3467 1
#  5: 22     235 2
#  6: 22    1234 1
#  7: 22     236 1
#  8: 22     134 1
#  9: 23    9133 1
# 10: 23     223 1
```

If you wanted the count of the *first* "feature", by "id", you could use:

```
DT[, .N, by = "id,feature"][, .SD[1], by = "id"]
#    id feature N
# 1: 21     234 3
# 2: 22     235 2
# 3: 23    9133 1
```

If you wanted to get the most frequently occurring "feature" by "id" (which is the same result as above, in this case), you can try the following:

```
DT[, .N, by = "id,feature"][, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[which.max(N)]), by = "id"]
```

---

### Update

Based on your new description, this seems much easier.

Just `merge` your datasets and `aggregate` the counts. Again, fast to do in "data.table":

```
DTY <- data.table(y, key = "id,feature")
DTX <- data.table(x, key = "id,feature")
DTY[DTX][, .N, by = id]
#    id N
# 1: 21 3
# 2: 22 2
# 3: 23 3
```

Or:

```
DTY[, .N, by = key(DTY)][DTX]
#    id feature N
# 1: 21     234 3
# 2: 22     235 2
# 3: 23     223 3
```

This is assuming that "x" and "y" are defined as the following to begin with:

```
x <- structure(list(id = 21:23, feature = c(234L, 235L, 223L),
  counts = c(3L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", "feature", "counts"),
  row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
y <- structure(list(id = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
  22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), feature = c(234L,
  290L, 234L, 7802L, 3467L, 234L, 235L, 235L, 1234L, 236L, 134L,
  9133L, 223L, 245L, 223L, 122L, 223L)), .Names = c("id", "feature"),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't know at first the position of the  feature I need to find. As u mentioned in the second part, that finds the occurrence of the first feature. But I don't know the position of the feature in the 'id-feature' dataframe. I just know what feature to find which is stored in different data frame. Suppose features to be found are stored in x, how do I write this command: 
DT[, .N, by = "id,feature"][, .SD[1], by = "id"]

Comment: I have edited the question, by specifying whats in x dataframe and what the final output should be. I feel its clear. Waiting for your answer....

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am really new to R. Can you refer me, where I can learn to write such commands...? .N and .SD arguments are new to me.

Comment: @ShreedharPawar, they are part of the "data.table" package and are documented in the man-pages and the vignettes that are available when you install and load the package.

Comment: Also, the  for loops that I have mentioned at the last give an error. The j in the inner loop increments everytime with elements mentioned in the positions array. The error says 'NA/NAn arguments in the for loop'. Is it because they vary everytime...?

Comment: @ShreedharPawar, Do your data fit in your memory? Why do you have to use the `for` loop?

Comment: @ShreedharPawar, as pointed out at another answer here, a 20GB CSV is not necessarily require 20GB of memory in R.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the data.table package for this (`fread` is very fast!), then set up a loop that loops through the file reading in chunks at a time and storing the feature count sums. Here are some adapted lines of a function I have for looping for a file, it probably won't work as is, but you can get an idea what to do

```
require(data.table)
LineNu <- as.numeric(gsub(" .+","",system2("wc",paste("-l",your.file,sep=" "),stdout=TRUE, stderr=TRUE)))
DT <- fread(your.file,nrows=50000000,sep=",",header=TRUE)
KEEP.DT <- DT[,list("feature"=sum(length(feature))),by=id]
rm(DT) ; gc()
Starts <- c(seq(50000000,LineNu,by=50000000),LineNu)
for (i in 2:(length(Starts)-1)) {
  cat(paste0("Filtering next 50000000 lines    ", i, " of ",length(Starts)-1, " \n"))
  DT <- fread(your.file,skip=Starts[i],nrows=ifelse(50000000*(i-1) < Starts[length(Starts)],50000000,(50000000*(i-1)) - Starts[length(Starts)]),sep=",",header=FALSE)
  DT[,list("feature"=sum(length(feature))),by=id]
  KEEP.DT <- rbind(KEEP.DT,DT)
  rm(DT) ; gc()
}
```

You may need to redo the DT[sum(length)] part since some id's might get read in in different chunks.

Comment: Using `data.table` the looping should not be required. `fread` is pretty fast as is most of the `by` processing.

Comment: I think the looping is required because the file is 20Gb and he has 16Gb of RAM.

Comment: 20GB CSV does not necessarily mean 20GB in memory within R

Answer (score 0):

For your example:

```
apply(sign(table(y)), 1, sum)
21 22 23 
 4  4  2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about table()?

```
> set.seed(5)
> ids <- sample(1:3, 12, TRUE)
> features <- sample(1:4, 12, TRUE)
> cbind(ids, features)
      ids features
 [1,]   1        2
 [2,]   3        3
 [3,]   3        2
 [4,]   1        1
 [5,]   1        2
 [6,]   3        4
 [7,]   2        3
 [8,]   3        4
 [9,]   3        4
[10,]   1        3
[11,]   1        1
[12,]   2        1

> table(ids, features)
   features
ids 1 2 3 4
  1 2 2 1 0
  2 1 0 1 0
  3 0 1 1 3
```

So for example feature 4 appears 3 times in id 3.

**EDIT**: You can use as.data.frame() to "flatten" the table and get:

```
> as.data.frame(table(ids, features))
   ids features Freq
1    1        1    2
2    2        1    1
3    3        1    0
4    1        2    2
5    2        2    0
6    3        2    1
7    1        3    1
8    2        3    1
9    3        3    1
10   1        4    0
11   2        4    0
12   3        4    3
```

Comment: I need to use the feature_count for further processing as a dataframe. table() will just give a representation.